# PYMC3: NUTS has difficulty sampling from a hierarchical zero inflated gamma model

Tags: python, pymc, pymc3

I'm trying to replicate the data analysis from [a paper from Richard McElreath](http://xcelab.net/rmpubs/Mcelreath%20Koster%202014.pdf), in which he fitted the data with a hierarchical zero inflated Gamma model. The data is about the hunting returns of around `15000` hunting trips from about `150` hunters over twenty years. Because a good many hunting trips have zero returns, the model assume each trip has `pi` probability of zero returns, and `1 - pi` probability of positive returns which follow a Gamma distribution with parameters `alpha` and `beta`.

The predictor variable is age, the model use an age polynomial (up to order 3) to model `pi` and `alpha`. And since the `15000` trips belong to `150` individual hunters, each hunter has coefficients of his own and all the coefficients follow a common multivariate normal distribution. For details of the model please refer to the following code. The model specification seems alright, but NUTS is having trouble start sampling: it gives only about 10 samples after about 20 minutes, and the sampler just halted there, and told me it will take hundreds of hours to finish the sampling. I want to know what is causing the problems.

The usual imports

```
import pymc3 as pm
import numpy as np
from pymc3.distributions import Continuous, Gamma
import theano.tensor as tt
```

The data can be obtained from [github](https://github.com/rmcelreath/mcelreath-koster-human-nature-2014)

```
n_trip = len(d)
n_hunter = len(d['hunter.id'].unique())
idx_hunter = d['hunter.id'].values

y = d['kg.meat'].values
age = d['age.s'].values
age2 = (d['age.s'].values)**2
age3 = (d['age.s'].values)**3
```

The log probability density function for Zero inflated Gamma.

```
class ZeroInflatedGamma(Continuous):
    def __init__(self, alpha, beta, pi, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ZeroInflatedGamma, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.beta = beta
        self.pi = pi = tt.as_tensor_variable(pi)
        self.gamma = Gamma.dist(alpha, beta)

    def logp(self, value):
        return tt.switch(value > 0,
                         tt.log(1 - self.pi) + self.gamma.logp(value),
                         tt.log(self.pi))
```

This is a matrix to index the correlation matrix prior to a 9X9 matrix, the LKJ prior in `pymc3` is given as a one dimentional vector

```
dim = 9
n_elem = dim * (dim - 1) / 2
tri_index = np.zeros([dim, dim], dtype=int)
tri_index[np.triu_indices(dim, k=1)] = np.arange(n_elem)
tri_index[np.triu_indices(dim, k=1)[::-1]] = np.arange(n_elem)
```

And here is the model

```
with pm.Model() as Vary9_model:

    # hyper-priors
    mu_a = pm.Normal('mu_a', mu=0, sd=100, shape=9)
    sigma_a = pm.HalfCauchy('sigma_a', 5, shape=9)

    # build the covariance matrix
    C_triu = pm.LKJCorr('C_triu', n=2, p=9)    
    C = tt.fill_diagonal(C_triu[tri_index], 1)
    sigma_diag = tt.nlinalg.diag(sigma_a)
    cov = tt.nlinalg.matrix_dot(sigma_diag, C, sigma_diag)

    # priors for each hunter and all the linear components, 9 dimensional Gaussian  
    a = pm.MvNormal('a', mu=mu_a, cov=cov, shape=(n_hunter, 9))

    # linear function  
    mupi = a[:,0][idx_hunter] + a[:,1][idx_hunter] * age + a[:,2][idx_hunter] * age2 + a[:,3][idx_hunter] * age3
    mualpha = a[:,4][idx_hunter] + a[:,5][idx_hunter] * age + a[:,6][idx_hunter] * age2 + a[:,7][idx_hunter] * age3

    pi = pm.Deterministic('pi', pm.math.sigmoid(mupi))
    alpha = pm.Deterministic('alpha', pm.math.exp(mualpha))
    beta = pm.Deterministic('beta', pm.math.exp(a[:,8][idx_hunter]))

    y_obs = ZeroInflatedGamma('y_obs', alpha, beta, pi, observed=y)

    Vary9_trace = pm.sample(6000, njobs=2)
```

And this is the status of the model:

```
Auto-assigning NUTS sampler...
Initializing NUTS using advi...
Average ELBO = -28,366: 100%|██████████| 200000/200000 [15:36<00:00, 213.57it/s]
Finished [100%]: Average ELBO = -28,365
  0%|          | 22/6000 [15:51<63:49:25, 38.44s/it]
```

I have some thoughts on the problem but not sure which might be the reason.

- is the nine dimensional Gaussian too difficult to sample with? I previously only modeled the intercepts for `mualpha` and `mupi` as bivariate Gaussian, it's slow but worked(the model fitting took about 20 minutes)
- is it the probability density that's causing the problem? I wrote the density function myself and am not sure if it's functioning well. I think the density function is not differentiable at zero, will this cause trouble for the nuts sampler?
- is it because the predictor variables are highly correlated? The linear model components in this model are polynomials of age, to the third degree, and naturally the predictors are highly correlated.

Or maybe it's because of something else?

As a side note, I tried using the `Metropolis` sampler, my computer has run out of memory and the chains still haven't converged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ZeroInflatedGamma looks fine. The density function is differentiable with respect to pi, alpha and beta. That is all you need for an observed variable. You only need the derivatives with respect to the value if you are trying to estimate the values.

There was an issue in the implementation of LKJCorr:
https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/pull/1863
You could try again on master. Sadly, pymc3 does not have support for using MVNormal and LKJCorr in cholesky decomposed parametrization. This might help, too. There is a work in progress pull request for this on github:
https://github.com/pymc-devs/pymc3/pull/1875

To improve convergence you could try a non-centered parameterization for `a`. Something along the lines of

```
a_raw = pm.Normal('a_raw', shape=(9, n_hunter))
a = mu_a[None, :] + tt.dot(tt.slinalg.cholesky(cov), a_raw)
```

Of course this would be faster if we had that cholesky LKJCorr...